# How can I change color of 3D surface on pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to change color of 3D surface like picture(exactly).
How is it possible?
[image]

```
  \documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain=-180:180,
        colorbar,
        colorbar style={
            title=Color key,
            ylabel=Z-value,
            ytick={-1,-0.75,...,1},
            yticklabel style={
                text width=2.5em,
                align=right,
                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                    fixed,
                    fixed zerofill
            }
        }
    ]
    \addplot3 [surf] {sin(x) * sin(y)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: You need to change the colormap. If you're lucky, there might be an existing one that meets your needs, otherwise you'll have to create one. texdoc pgfplots and search for colormap

Comment: Thank you. But I have problem, when I run the above code, there is an Error as, ! I can't find file `pgflibrarypgfplots.colorbrewer.code.tex'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The colormap in your right image is the [PuYG colormap from the ColorBrewer website](http://colorbrewer2.org/?type=diverging&scheme=PiYG&n=11). PGFPlots contains a library that provides the colormaps from the website.

To use the colormaps, put `\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}` in the preamble and activate the desired colormap using `colormap/PuYG`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=-180:180,
samples=50,
colormap/PiYG,
colorbar,
colorbar style={
    title=Color key,
    ylabel=Z-value,
    ytick={-1,-0.75,...,1},
    yticklabel style={
        text width=2.5em,
        align=right,
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            fixed zerofill
        }
    }
]
\addplot3 [surf] {sin(x) * sin(y)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have problem, when I run the above code, there is an Error as, 
! I can't find file `pgflibrarypgfplots.colorbrewer.code.tex'.

Comment: @sayros: You need to update your PGFplots package